# databricks scala recall the variable outside the if loop

Tags: scala, databricks

I am doing the following

```
var total_count=1
if (total_count>=1)
{
  var next_exec_no="2"

} else
{
  var next_exec_no="1"
}
print(next_exec_no)
```

However there is problem when calling print(next_exec_no)   outside the if loop
having error

error: not found: value next_exec_no
print(next_exec_no)

Any idea ?

Comment: Please first (at least) read the base tutorials (like https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html )

Answer (score 0):

*next_exec_no* is out of scope, in this case this variable is visible only inside the two if branch. Substantially you are defining two new variables

P.S. i suggest you to use scala in a functional way, so you shouldn't use **var** but **val**

**Solutions**

*Mutable Approach:*

```
var total_count=1
var next_exec_no=""

if (total_count>=1)
{
  next_exec_no="2"

} else {
  next_exec_no="1"
}

print(next_exec_no)
```

*Immutable FP Approach:*

```
val next_exec_no = if(total_count >= 1) "2" else "1"
print(next_exec_no)
```

Comment: That's not OOP approach, but mutable approach, and that's why that's not the recommended one in Scala (even if local mutation can be harmless/efficient).

Comment: You're right, i wrote OOP thinking about standard approach in common no functional OOP language.

Comment: the already declared outside the if loop can't be referencing inside the loop